# Movable Rectangle or Label

Tags: c#, winforms, highlight

I am writing a program in Visual C# 2010 that has several icons on the form. When the mouse is placed over the icon (which is just an image) I want the icon to b highlighted via a border around the icon. In visual basic i can make a transparent rectangle with a colored border and position it over the icon. In C#, i can do the same however until i call invalidate multiple borders appear. The problem with calling invalidate is that my program is doing something in the background every second so the border keeps flashing (re-drawing).

Anyone got any ideas how i can implement this?

Comment: This is pretty vague.  Just use a ListView, it is already capable of displaying icons in a grid and highlighting them.  Use View = Large or View = Tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn’t say *how* you draw the border but from your description you are creating a graphics context for this. Don’t do this, it’s wrong. Instead, draw inside the `Paint` element of either the control or the its parent container.

The [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event handler could look as follows:

```
private void yourControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (! HasFocus(yourControl))
        return;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 128)))
        g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, yourControl.Width -1, yourControl.Height - 1);
}
```

This uses a hypothetical `HasFocus` method to determine whether this control should have a focus rectangle.

By the way, this is identical in VB and C#.